# VBA Lookup Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I reviewed previous questions on this and can't locate an answer. I am using a VLOOKUP within VBA to populate a userform with the data based on the selection. I continue to get mismatch on certain entries and others worked, now none work. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub jobRefCbo_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call Lists_sort ' This just sorts a list of the 'Active' data so the user only sees the active jobs in the combo box. 



    Me.nameTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 2, False)
    'Me.acNoTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 2, False)
    Me.jobDesc2Txt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 3, False)
    'Me.date2Txt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 4, False)
    Me.month2Txt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 5, False)
    Me.timeOnJobTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 6, False)
    Me.StatusTxt.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 7, False)
    Me.startTime2Txt.Value = Format(CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDbl(Me.jobRefCbo.Value), Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21"), 8, False)), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any advice in doing this in general is much appreciated.

Comment: First: the more times a macro touches a worksheet, the longer the code takes to run. Second: VLookup sometimes fails when trying to match a number to the string-representation of that same number or vice versa.  I would recommend pulling the data from the sheet into an array in excel, cycling through the column with the "match" to identify the row, then pulling the information from the identified row in the array.

Comment: It seems it only mismatches when a letter is used in the job reference lookup. I am testing this now.

Comment: You were head on the nail Mistella, IT must be the String interpretation that is causing the error. IF I may ask, how do I convert the data to an array?

Comment: If that's the case, it would be caused by the `CDbl` function that's wrapping `Me.jobRefCbo.Value`. `CDbl` converts to double, which is a number type. If the `Me.jobRefCbo.Value` ever contains non-digits, the `CDbl` function will error

Comment: Simplest fix would probably be to remove `CDbl`, but if you want to work on speeding up the code, I can add more info on pulling data into an array.

Comment: Since I'm not sure how using WorksheetFunctions affects the speed of the code, it may help to assign a long with `WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.jobRefCbo.Value,Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:I21"),0)` as this will identify the correct row. Then you could assign values like `Me.nameTxt.Value = Worksheets("Lists ").Range("J" & rowVariable)`

Comment: Mistella I'd like to really thank you for taking the time out to provide all this learning. I didn't know that's what CBdl did. I am excited to try the code you have displayed here, it will make the tool/code a lot cleaner! Thanks again, I really appreciate the help. I would really appreciate any assistance with pulling data into an array.

Comment: Mistrella,  when I enter the code:

Private Sub jobRefCbo_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.jobRefCbo.Value, Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:I21"), 0)

It gives me an 'Expected =' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions for fixes:

```
Private Sub jobRefCbo_Change()

    Dim m, v, rngSearch As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Lists_sort 'use of Call is deprecated

    v = Trim(Me.jobRefCbo.Value)

    If IsNumeric(v) Then
        Set rngSearch = Worksheets("Lists ").Range("I3:P21")
        'use Match to find a hit in the first column...
        m = Application.Match(CDbl(v), rngSearch.Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'got a hit so return the values
            With rngSearch.Rows(m)
                Me.nameTxt.Value = .Cells(2).Value
                Me.jobDesc2Txt.Value = .Cells(3).Value
                'etc etc
            End With
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Lookup value must be numeric", vbExclamation
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow I can't thank you enough, I appreciate you taking the time out to post this. It has been a massive help.

Comment: @edgarc1981 Just in case you aren't aware, if Tim's answer solved your issue, you can accept it as your preferred answer by clicking the check mark located directly under the vote buttons.

Comment: Thank you, I have done so. Thanks for the guidance and your patience with me as I learn the platform. The tool works perfectly now thanks to your expertise!